# Почему получается не удобный --graph коммитов в git?

Tags: git

Недавно изучаю git. Попалось [видео](https://youtu.be/dnT8YzpqEYA?list=PLDyvV36pndZFHXjXuwA_NywNrVQO0aQqb) про флаг `-x` в `git rebase`. На картинке, как показано в видео, вырисовывается удобный граф с ветками, а не линейный, как у меня:

```rb
* ee1b9cf (HEAD -> feature) Call say() in feature.mjs
* 61b188c Import lib.mjs to feature.mjs
* d4d7019 (master) Rename say() to sayHi()
* 52f128b Create say() in lib.mjs
```

Возможно, `--no-ff` поможет, но нет. Как исправить не красивый линейный граф или это такая *ФИЧА* `rebase`?

Comment: На видео просто красивая картинка которая поясняет как работает rebase. Флаг `-x` просто запускает команду (тесты) после каждого шага что бы проще было найти момент когда всё ломается.

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю, что от флага это не зависит, но во всех случаях `rebase` делает линейный граф или есть способы это исправить?

Comment: Эм, как бы в этом и смысл ребейза.

Comment: `rebase` переносит коммиты на другую ветку. То есть меняет самого первого родителя ветки, которую надо перебазировать. Я правильно понял?

Comment: На видео получается линейный граф. В результате выполнения rebase может быть получение как линейного, так и разветвленного дерева коммитов. Но обычно имеет смысл стараться держать дерево более-менее линейным.

Comment: То есть мы никак не можем повлиять на тип дерева?

Comment: Что значит "повлияять"? В каком месте и в каком смысле повлиять? С каждым коммитом вы влияете на тип дерева. Если все линейное, то и дерево линейное, если много разных веток, то и дерево ветвистое.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял